# How does Couchbase work with Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase, elasticsearch-plugin

I understand there is a plugin that allows couchbase to replicate its data to an Elasticsearch cluster. My question is - how does this work if I already have an existing set of data in couchbase?

Will this replicate one document at a time, or in batches? How safe is the replication as it occurs? What happens in the event of network failure? Couchbase failure? Elasticsearch failure? Is this configurable?

Answer (score 1):

As the [Couchbase Documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/elastic/connect-to-cluster.html) says, the elasticsearch plugin uses couchbase cross-datacenter replication (xdcr) to achieve integration with elasticsearch.

You can read up on the specifics xdcr if you are curious, but the end result is that you end up with couchbase as the master and elasticsearch as the slave. Data is transferred in small batches depending on network performance. Xdcr is fault-tolerant and partition-tolerant. Your data stored in couchbase is not affected.

Answer (score 1):

In Couchbase you can create an elastic search Cluster by declaring the port(9091) and host name to which your elasticsearch in installed.

By creating replication from couchbase bucket to elastic seaarch node we can replicate data in the couchbase to elastic search. Data replication take place by the couchbase-elastic search transport.It continously transfer data from couchbase to elastic search.

By checking http://localhost:9091/pools and entering your couchbase username and password (get request) bucket uuid through which the data transfer take place.